# sdkmanager install cmake fails

Tags: android, android-studio

I trying to install cmake (`3.10.2`) using following command on `Ubuntu`

```
/opt/android-sdk/tools/bin/sdkmanager --install "cmake;3.10.2"
```

But getting

```
Warning: Failed to find package cmake;3.10.2
```

What I am missing here ?

*Update :*

I had to use following command

```
/opt/android-sdk/tools/bin/sdkmanager --install "cmake;3.10.2.4988404"
```

which worked, but how can I get 3.10.2.**xxxxxxx** commit number for any package ?

Answer (score 2):

According to the docs from Android Developer, you can only install the CMake versions included by SDK Manager.

https://developer.android.com/studio/projects/install-ndk#vanilla_cmake

So run `your_sdk_root_path/tools/bin/sdkmanager  --list | grep  "cmake"` to find all the included CMake versions.

```
  cmake;3.10.2.4988404                                | 3.10.2       | CMake 3.10.2.4988404                            | cmake/3.10.2.4988404/                               
  cmake;3.6.4111459                                   | 3.6.4111459  | CMake 3.6.4111459                               | cmake/3.6.4111459/                                  
  cmake;3.10.2.4988404                                                                     | 3.10.2       | CMake 3.10.2.4988404                                                
  cmake;3.18.1                                                                             | 3.18.1       | CMake 3.18.1                                                        
  cmake;3.6.4111459                                                                        | 3.6.4111459  | CMake 3.6.4111459
```

Otherwise, you have to download the CMake version from the official CMake website.

https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/sdkmanager#list_installed_and_available_packages

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me :
`sdkmanager.bat  cmake;3.10.2.4988404`